# Executing script in one terminal window(s) from other window

Tags: bash, terminal, gnu-screen

I am using `screen` to create multiple shells inside a terminal window. 
If I execute a script in one shell and create a new screen using `ctrl+a c`, is there any way that after creating the screen, the script currently executing in first shell issue a command to new created shell screen.

For instance, I have a script as:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line
do
echo $line;
for x in {a..d}
do
    bash t.sh $line/x$x 
    xdotool key ctrl+a c
done
done < files
```

`files` file contain a folder name containing data files.

Now this script when executed, execute a script `t.sh` and then creates a new screen and continue the loop. 
Now at the end I end up with 4 screen shells but the script `t.sh` got executed 4 time in first shell only.
So, I need to basically execute the script `t.sh` in 4 shells individually.

(P.S.: My base requirement is that I have a 132 core CPU and want to execute a script 132 times individually and track output of each of the execution.)

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question directly, you can issue commands from one `screen` window to another using the [`at` command](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#At), which can be invoked through `screen -X`.

**Your case is simpler, though:** Rather than issuing a `ctrl+a c` keypress, just call `screen bash t.sh $line/x$x`. Invoking `screen` from within a `screen` session will [create a new process in the same session](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#Overview) by default (unless the `$STY` environment variable is cleared).

Comment: Thanks for your response,Jeff. But this command returns `Must be connected to a terminal.` error.

Comment: I haven't been able to reproduce that problem, after a few tries. Can you share enough of what you have that I can reproduce?

Comment: I just replaced `bash t.sh $line/x$x` line by `screen bash t.sh $line/x$x` in above code mentioned in question.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really want to execute the script from other terminal? If you just want to do it for easier monitoring, you can do this:

```
# my other terminal where I want to see the output:
$ tty
/dev/pts/xx  #<~~~~ note this tty device number

# my main terminal:
$ bash t.sh $line/x$x </dev/pts/xx >/dev/pts/xx 2>&1
```

Comment: Thanks for your response @anishsane. According to your solution, the script is basically executing in the main terminal but its output is getting transferred to other terminal. But what I need is to transfer the complete execution to other terminal.

Comment: stdin, stdout, stderr are transferred. Other environment is not transferred. Most commonly, this is what I would need. but your requirement could be different.